# Cannot create Django Project in PyDev

Tags: python, django, eclipse, ubuntu, pydev

I am running Eclipse Kepler 4.3 with PyDev 3.0 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTE. I have default Python 2.7 installed. I have installed Django with:

```
sudo pip install django
```

I have installed PyDev from update site and configured interpreter with Quick Auto-Config. I can see `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` path in Libraries section where Django is installed.

I can create normal PyDev projects successfully and I can see `django` package in System Libs. But when I try to create PyDev Django project, 'Next' and 'Finish' buttons are disabled. So I can't create the project. I am not seeing any error but the buttons stay disabled for any project name.

Is this a PyDev bug or a mistake in interpreter configuration? Can anyone suggest how to resolve it?

**Update:** I have just got it working. If I create a simple PyDev project and keep it in workspace. After that I can create PyDev Django projects successfully. But if I delete simple PyDev project, it stops working again. So for a workaround, I have created a dummy PyDev project and kept it in my workspace. However, it would be good if someone can suggest a proper solution.

Comment: I use aptana and pydev and i got autocomplete working when i removed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django from the config and replaced it with the folder where i unpacked the django file i downloaded from djangoproject.com

Comment: It seems you hit a bug (still haven't tried to reproduce it). Can you report that at the PyDev tracker: https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/PyDev/ ?

Comment: Same problem and creating a dummy project in workspace worked. As a newbie that is more comfortable than installing 'nightly builds'

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Fabio above, it was a bug in PyDev.
It has now been corrected (thanks Fabio)

To make it working:

1. Add Pydev Nightly builds to your update sites
2. Upgrade to build 3.2.1 (stable versions 3.2.0.x or lower do not include the fix)

It worked for me

Env:

- Ubuntu 13.10
- Eclipse 4.2.2
- Python interpreters 2.7 & 3.3

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by installing the "nightly build" version of Pydev as per Jan's suggestion.

Steps:
1) Uninstall any previous versions from Eclipse (Help > Install New Software ...already installed > Select pydev and uninstall

2) Install the new version (Help > Install new software > Add ... > Enter Name: "Pydev Nightly", Location: "http://nightly.aptana.com/pydev/site.xml"

3) Install and restart.  You should now be able to go File > New > Other... > PyDev > Pydev Project

Comment: It worked for me  a year back, but now this location is unavailable

Answer (score 1):

In my case it worked with PyDev 4.5

Open Eclipse Kepler.
Go to > Help > Install New Software.

Click on Add..
Add a new repository

Name: pydev4.5

Location: https://dl.bintray.com/fabioz/pydev/4.5.0/

Click on Ok

Wait few seconds and it shows PyDev package above.
Select PyDev, click on Next and go on

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade PyDev. I have been running with the same problem when update Django to 1.5. Even the folder structure of projects is different.